# Java - Using different logging libraries and use interface to create it

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I've got an issue :

- Project A : Commons library, logging interface with default method names.
- Project B : Library, implement this Project A logging interface and need to log some things.
- Project C : Android project, using a particular logger.
- Project D : Java API, using a particular logger (different than the Project C)

So when project C and D use the B library this library should log using differents logger (Log4J for the API (D) and another for Android(C))
How should I implement the logger method in Project B so it can be dependent of the C and D logging library ?

Project A interface :

```
public interface Logger {
void warn(String message, Class<?> clazz);
void info(String message, Class<?> clazz);
void error(String message, Class<?> clazz);
void verbose(String message, Class<?> clazz);
void debug(String message, Class<?> clazz);
}
```

Project B implementation :

```
public class LoggerImpl implements Logger {

    private Class logger;

    public void LoggerImpl1() {

    }
    @Override
    public void warn(String s, Class<?> aClass) {
        // Need to use different logger, depending on API or Android
    }
    
    @Override
    public void info(String s, Class<?> aClass) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void error(String s, Class<?> aClass) {

    }

    @Override
    public void verbose(String s, Class<?> aClass) {

    }

    @Override
    public void debug(String s, Class<?> aClass) {

    }
}
```

How can I implement this ?
Thanks.